# vncserver on ubuntu 18.04 - viewer shows terminal on host

Tags: ubuntu, vncserver, vnc-viewer

I would like to setup vncserver on my ubuntu 18.04 host. My ~/.vnc/xstartup file looks like -

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec startxfce4
```

I launch the server with command line -

```
vncserver
```

Which launches the server.

My my windows machine I start a viewer which is able to connect to my ubunut 18.04 LTS vncserver. I am able to see the ubuntu desktop, disks and GUI etc. My problem is when I right click mouse on windows vncviewer, and look to launch a terminal, the terminal showup on screen of host (i.e. ubuntu machine) and not on viewer !

Would appreciate any help to fix this.

Thanks.